# Rails 6: Cannot install pg on mac m1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I tried installing the gem pg on my mac m1 but am getting this error:

`ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)`

`You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0 directory.`

I installed postgresql with homebrew and can connect on a database with the command psql. This means I have postgres install on my machine but the gem pg doesn't work on rails.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to use `sudo` and force permissions, however it may not be the best solution.

https://www.moncefbelyamani.com/the-definitive-guide-to-installing-ruby-gems-on-a-mac/

Looks like a good article, you should probably go with https://www.moncefbelyamani.com/the-definitive-guide-to-installing-ruby-gems-on-a-mac/#ruby-manager

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed PostgreSQL with Homebrew, that means you have the write permission to the related directory, **as long as** you execute the command (be it *rails*-related or pure *Ruby*) with the same privilege as you installed PostgreSQL. So, if you have installed PostgreSQL with `sudo`, then you should run `sudo gem install pg` or whatever, using `sudo`. Or, if you have switched your account to an administrator who controls Homebrew software, then you must do the same in running `gem install pg` (note that this latter case can be complicated in terms of permission if you combine it with a Rails project installed under a user's directory).

Personally, I use `rbenv` ([Github](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv)) for the version control software of Ruby (or, a popular alternative `rvm` should work fine, too), while Homebrew installation is limited to administrators only in my environment. With `rbenv`, all the Ruby libraries are under each user's control, as everything (but external software like PostgreSQL) is installed under the user's Home directory. This sort of permission-conflict (which really is a pain as I experienced countless times with Rails in the past!) would not happen if you use `rbenv` (or `rvm`).